# How to create persistent VxLAN interface across reboots

Tags: linux, network-interface

On Redhat 7.3, I can create a VxLAN interface using  -- 
`ip link add vxlan type vxlan id 42 group 239.1.1.1 dev eth1 dstport 4789`
and assign an IP address. It works. But, this interface is gone on a reboot.

My question is, how do I create a VxLAN interface persistent across reboots?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old but the simplest way is to create a shell script that executes on boot

Create a shell script called something like vxlan1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
ip link add vxlan type vxlan id 42 group 239.1.1.1 dev eth1 dstport 4789
```

then do `chmod +x vxlan.sh`
Now you need to simply execute that script on boot.
Here is a stack overflow discussion on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `ifcfg` VXLAN interface file.
It requires adding two options:

```
VXLAN='yes'
VXLAN_ID='3'
```

`VXLAN` defines that this `ifcfg` file create a specification of VXLAN interface.
`VXLAN_ID` specifies a unique VXLAN indentifier in the 'real' network. Every your VXLAN has to have a unique `VXLAN_ID`. See `ifcfg-vxlan(5)`.